# How fix the error that I got in linear regression in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am new in the concept of linear regression in Python. I am using the linear regression in scikit-learn to find the predicted value of y, here it is called y_new. The below code is what I have scripted so far:

```
import numpy as np 
#creating data for the run
x=spendings = np.linspace(0,5,4000)
y=sales = np.linspace(0,0.5,4000)
#defining the training function
def train(x,y):
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    model = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
    return model 
model = train(x,y)
x_new = 23.0
y_new = model.predict([[x_new]])
print(y_new)
```

I can't get the value of the y_new due to this error message:

```
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.00000000e+00 1.25031258e-03 2.50062516e-03 ... 4.99749937e+00
 4.99874969e+00 5.00000000e+00].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full error traceback to see which line is causing the error; that being said, have you done what the error message suggests? "use `array.reshape(-1, 1)` if your data has a single feature or `array.reshape(1, -1)` if it contains a single sample"?

Comment: -@G.Anderson, the error is related to the defined function "train". The full error traceback gives this message. I had to cut a couple of sentences from the error to fit this message here:
----> 9 model = train(x,y)
----> 6     model = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
--> 463                          y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
--> 719                     estimator=estimator)
--> 521                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

Comment: It tells you the problem: "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead", and it tells you the solution: `array.reshape(-1, 1)`, so have you attempted to reshape your data into the correct shape, and what was your result?

Comment: _@G.Anderson, since I am new in this field, I don't know how to reshape the data and I don't get any result so far.

Comment: The error message says exactly what the problem is, and provides a solution. Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: -@AMC, I don't understand what the error message says and I don't understand what is the suggested solution in the given error message.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [LinearRegression fit method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) expects X and y input to be **(n_samples, n_features)** shape.

if you check your x and y shapes,it is like this

```
x=spendings = np.linspace(0,5,4000)
y=sales = np.linspace(0,0.5,4000)
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)

(4000,)
(4000,)
```

what error says,you need to reshape your x and y to shape **(n_samples, n_features)** using `arr.reshape(-1,1)`.
so what you need is [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) your x and y before fit to the LinearRegression.

```
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
(4000, 1)
(4000, 1)
```